# How to know if Android resolved to use a localized strings.xml file or the default one?

Tags: android

The motivation of this question comes from this other question:

**How do I get the current language my app is in?** (Not the device's language as specified in the Settings. I want the language *that Android resolved to use for my app*).

This question has been asked several times on the site, but it fails to consider this corner-case:

Imagine the user has only one preferred language in his device: say German, for example.

My app two `strings.xml` files: The default one, and one in French (`values-fr/strings.xml`).

Obviously, Android will resolve to use the default `strings.xml` in this case.

But if I do any of the following, it will return `German`:

`Locale.getDefault()`
`getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)`
`getResources().getConfiguration().locale`.
(And many other suggestions that I have found on the site)

And who told Android that the default `strings.xml` file was in German? Why did it made that assumption? The default file could be in Spanish, Italian, Polish...whatever.

Ideally, I would like a method that returns `null` in this case. Some method that tells me that no match was found for German and Android had to fall-back to the default `strings.xml`.

Does such method exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the language name in both strings.xml files. For example, as languageName.
When you get the string for R.string.languageName, it will be the language chosen by Android among the ones you support.

Comment: This is a great workaround. It's actually what I'm doing in my app. However it is hacky. The downside is that you need to add a new string entry in ALL of your strings.xml files. That could be a lot. I was wondering if there was a more official way. If no one else suggests a better answer I'll mark yours as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions all return the phone's locale.  They have nothing to do with resource localization.  So nobody said the strings.xml file was German.  The user set the phone to German, and the resource subsystem decided strings.xml was the best match for that.  Basically you have the way it works backwards.

I don't think there is a way to get what you want for two reasons:

1)It's supposed to be transparent to the programmer.

2)It doesn't pick one file over the other.  It picks independently for each string.  So if you have a strings.xml with two strings A and B, and had a german strings file with only A, it would give you the german A and the default B.

Comment: I think that the methods I listed are counter-intuitive. They return different things in different circumstances. On one hand, the methods return the locale that Android resolved to use for the app. But if there's no match, they return the locale of the device itself. So basically, there is no 100% trustworthy way to get the current locale of the app.